# How to update an image when coming back from the profile page in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have a requirement to update an image on my Dashboard once it has been updated on next page (the profile page).

Navigation : Dashboard -> Profile page -> Update Image -> Dashboard (back button pressed)

XAML

```
    <ImageButton x:Name="profilePicThumbnail"
                 ....
                 Command="{Binding UserProfileBtn}"
                 IsVisible="{Binding IsRemotePic}">
           <ImageButton.Source>
                 <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding UserPic, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 CachingEnabled="false"/>
           </ImageButton.Source>

    </ImageButton>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
    private Uri userpic;
    public Uri UserPic
    {
        get { return userpic; }
        set
        {
            userpic = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

How I feed the UserPic

```
    UserPic = new Uri(dash.student_details.profile_pic); //URL as a string
```

However my image is not updated, though i call the relative method after updating it in the Profile Page and come back to the Dashboard. **Url string i receive from the backend is always same** (But the image is different after the update)

Is there a way i can achieve this??

Comment: Since the URI doesn't change, the property changed won't fire. Can you "trick" it by setting UserPic to null, then back to the correct URI?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Another way is to use  [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0) or [WeakReferenceMessenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) (for WeakReferenceMessenger you have to install [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) package from nuget.org).

Suppose there is a Clicked method for button in ProfilePage to update the UserPic. In ProfilePage in this method, we send a message to tell the viewmodel of Dashboard to update UserPic.

```
    void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri newUri = new Uri("...");
        MessagingCenter.Send<ProfilePage, Uri>(this, "Hi", newUri);
    }
```

So in DashboardViewModel, we just subscribe this message then to update the value.

```
public DashboardViewModel()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ProfilePage, Uri>(this, "Hi", (sender, arg) =>
    {
        UserPic = arg;
    });
}
```

Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Now when you navigate back or press back button, the value should be updated.

And If you want to use WeakReferenceMessenger, that is almost the same,

send the message:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage(item));
```

receive the message:

```
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, item) =>
    {
        UserPic = item.value;
    });
```

If you have any question, feel free to ask.

===================**origin answer**===============

If I understand correctly, you wannt to update the property of Dashboard in ProfilePage. I made a demo to share my idea.

Suppose there is a Clicked method for button in ProfilePage to update the UserPic.

In this method, we do the following things:

1. first create the Dashboard page and
2. then change the UserPic property of bindingContext (ViewModel page binds to)
3. finally navigate to the Dashboard page

   ```
    void mybutton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = new Dashboard();
        DashboardViewModel bindingContext = page.BindingContext as DashboardViewModel;
        // Here you could change the ViewModel's UserPic, then navigation
        bindingContext.UserPic = new Uri(...);
        Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    }
   ```

Don't forget set the BindingContext for Dashboard:

```
this.BindingContext = new DashboardViewModel();
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: `Navigation.PushAsync(page);` will this add a new Page on the Navigation Stack? My Profile Page will fall on the Current Navigation stack and upon updating the Image i want to pop it out and get the update on the bottom page, which is my dashboard.. Nevertheless i will try this code too

Comment: @Thush-Fdo Hi, I have updated my answer using MessagingCenter. You could have a try.

Comment: If use ```Navigation.PushAsync```, it will create a new page instance and add it on the top of Navigation Stack.